# Gnome-Terminal mark text > copy to clipboard (like in xfce4-terminal)

Tags: gnome-terminal, clipboard, terminal-emulator, xfce4-terminal

I switched a few days ago from xfce4 to cinnamon. Quite an improvement in usability. However, I miss the function of the xfce4-terminal that I can mark text and that it is automatically copied to the cliboard. Wasn't able to find it in the gnome-terminal settings, manual and a startpage-research did not give any results.

Is there a way I can make the gnome-terminal (Version 3.36.2) copying text I mark? Or do I need to install the xfce4-terminal for that? Or do you have any other pro suggestions for a terminal-emulator?

Thanks.

Comment: If you like `xfce4-terminal`, it's usually available as a stand-alone package and can be installed without issue. With Debian-based distros simply `apt install xfce4-terminal`. On my gnome-based installation I only need an extra 2.7MB to install xcfe4-terminal.

Comment: @Stewart thank you. I know. However, I'd like to know, if there are any other terminal emulators recommended and/or if it is possible with the gnome-terminal as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work-around, which is even better:

> *Anything* you highlight in Linux, regardless of the program, is put
> into a special clipboard buffer, which you can paste using your
> mouse's middle (wheel) button (which is emulated on many laptops by
> pushing both buttons at the same time)

source https://superuser.com/a/307371/1270261

Bytheway: here is a good compilation of different terminal-emulators
https://fossbytes.com/best-linux-terminal-emulators/